# Connection Time Out in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

What I am doing is 40k+ records checking using SQL 2008, asp.net c#.

Now I am facing the following error.

[image]

Here is my config.

```
<add name="Test" connectionString="Data Source=MyComputer;Initial Catalog=MYDatabase;Trusted_Connection=true; Timeout=1200; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=300; Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 

<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1348576" executionTimeout="4322000"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this is a request timeout for the page or a SQL timeout? Can you connect using SSMS? How long does the query take to run?

Comment: @Liath There are 4k+ records in the database.
1. Select those 4k+ records from the database and add in the dataTable.
2. Loop the datatable and update each record to the database.
Is my logic wrong something ? It's taking about 2 hours.

Comment: The words "loop" and "Database" always make me nervous. 4000 rows are not a lot, I'd check your logic and make sure you've not got an N+1 problem or something similar

Comment: Please don't add your config text as an image, but as text. It is not very easy to read and copy it to test it ourselves.

Comment: Also, processing 4000 rows, row by row, sounds like a bad idea. Can't you update then at once, or prepare an sql statement and fire that at once.

Comment: @Liath Sorry to make you nervous. There are 47500 records in the table.

Comment: @Lamin I think the issue here is the performance of your query rather than the timeout! I'd suggest opening a new question with details

Comment: @Lamin: That amount shouldn't worry you. The fact that you update them all at row-by-row from .NET is bad. Just think of the connection overhead you might have.

Comment: I will open a new question. :) Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing 4000 rows, row by row, sounds like a bad idea. If the update takes two hours, you should rethink your solution.

Options:

- Create a the SQL statements upfront and execute them at once;
- Create and call a procedure in the database doing this job for you;
- Run this in a background process, maybe using an async method, and report process back to the client.

---

*Previous solution, just to be complete:*

You have to set the timeout longer is the connection timeout of your database connection is longer the the default timeout.

Add this to your web.config under `system.web`:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" />
```

This sets the timeout to 1200 seconds. I would make sure first that you optimize your SQL statement to you don't need this and set it to the lowest value you really need.

Comment: we were discussing the same topic in office today..what a coincidence :)